# Redirect to 404 if filename passed as parameter does not exitsts

Tags: nginx, redirect, file-server, scripting

I have special parameter `data=/path/to/filename.htm` in uri.

Its old and rusty site builded on SSI, and I can't modify it.

Problem is when filename passed as arg_data not exists, page is broken.

I want redirect to 404.htm in this case.

Something like that:

```
if (!-f $arg_data){
     rewrite ^.*$  /404.htm last;
   }
```

But I get:

> rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/404.htm

I think its because I didn't check `if arg_data` exists.

But nginx have not nested if-s.

I tried:

```
set $data index.htm;                                                                                                                                               
if ($args ~ "data=(.+)") {                                                                                                                                         
    set $data $1;                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
if (!-f $data) {                                                                                                                                                
    rewrite ^.*$  /404.htm last;                                                                                                                                   
}
```

Idea was set `$data` to some file which 100% exists, and after that rewrite if data param is passed.

For some reason its give the same error, internal redirection cycle

Looks like I do it in wrong way.

Comment: You need to be using `try_files`. This is not Apache where you have to rewrite everything.

Comment: I have "inversed logic". 404 if $data NOT exists, what to try?

Comment: Inverse of what? That is a perfectly normal circumstance. Show your entire `server` block so that we can figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Aha, ok. My example. Uri is: /detail.htm?data=product.htm. I must show  the detail.htm if exists product.htm, and 404.htm otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so regarding the last comments we had, you need an `AND` condition for two `if` statements.

`NGinx` is not able to do this.

To achieve this, we will use a little trick dealing with a `$test` var :

```
server {

  #...directives...

  error_page 404 /404.htm;

  if ($args != "") {                  # Test if there are some args       
     set $test A;
  }

  if (!-f /full/path/to/$arg_data) {  # Test if file in args doesn't exist
     set $test "${test}B";
  }

  if ($test = AB) {       # If there are some args AND if file doesn't exist
     return 404;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Its new trick for me. I saw it in bash, but forget

Comment: You know what man ? i've worked 2 days (not full time) on your issue !

Comment: Wow!! I hope you have some fun with it.

Comment: Of course i had ! If not, i won't do this ;)

Answer (score 3):

OK, this is a very strange scenario, and you seem to be on the right track.

Instead of the `rewrite`, though, I would `return 404;` and use an `error_page` to define the 404 error page.

For example:

```
server {

    #...your other stuff...

    error_page 404 /404.htm;

    if (!-f $arg_data){
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Entire config : https://gist.github.com/korjavin/9181939 Its still show index.htm even if aaa.htm not exists in uri index.htm?data=aaa.htm

Comment: @Korjavin Ivan Try with `if (!-f /full/path/to/$arg_data)`

Comment: Oh, yes, much closer. But big problem if this $arg_data not passed to uri. I also need to do that ONLY if $arg_data exists. Nested if again.

Comment: @Korjavin Ivan Ok, i've written an answer to deal with this problem